# Surface Area bounded by Geodesics

Tags: surface-integrals, spheres, noneuclidean-geometry

Is there a formula for calculating the surface area of a region on a sphere which is bounded by 3 geodesics? Or, given three points on a sphere is there a way to calculate the surface area of the region bounded by the 3 geodesics going through those points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geodesics are great circles in spherical geometry. (If we measure arc length in the embedding Euclidean 3D space.)

So, we are talking about spherical triangles. [The area of a spherical triangle](http://planetmath.org/AreaOfASphericalTriangle) is

$$(\alpha+\beta+\gamma-\pi)*R^2$$
where the angles are the angles between the corresponding tangent lines (by the definition the spherical angle.) As shown below.

[image: ![enter image description here]